# longtabu Missing } inserted error

Tags: compiling

I'm getting this error:

```
(./template/changelog.tex
./template/changelog.tex:36: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.36 \end{longtabu}
```

while I compile a multifile project.

changelog.tex:

```
\newcommand*\mytablecontents{}
\foreach \x [count=\nj] in \modifiche
{
    \foreach \y [count=\ni] in \x
    {
        \ifnum\ni=5
            \xappto\mytablecontents{\y}
            \gappto\mytablecontents{\\}
            \gappto\mytablecontents{\hline}
        \else
            \xappto\mytablecontents{\y&}
        \fi
    }
}

\section*{Diario delle modifiche}

% Impostazioni della tabella
\tabulinesep = 2mm % padding
\taburowcolors 2{pari .. dispari} % colori delle righe

\begin{longtabu}{|X[-1,c]|X[-1,c]|X[1,c]|X[0.6,c]|X[1.3]|} % larghezza delle colonne
\hline

\rowcolor{header} % colore dell'header

% header
\textbf{Versione} & \textbf{Data} & \textbf{Nominativo}             & \textbf{Ruolo}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Descrizione}}\\
\hline

\endfirsthead
\endhead

\mytablecontents

\end{longtabu}
```

I don't understand where `}` is missing.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem.

Comment: tabu is buggy and unmaintained. Its use is not recommended, see the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu

Comment: This stops to work with TeX Live 2018. Don't use `tabu`. That's all. If you describe the final aim, with a full example of how you build `\mytablecontents` and the whole set of needed packages and colors, we could possibly help in finding a solution.